# How to store multple columns object in DataTable Row

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, reference

How can I store object in DataTable Row expanded to few columns or have object in one column and reference properties to this object in other?

```
class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable
    {
        this.Columns.Add("col1");
        this.Columns.Add("col2")        
        this.Columns.Add("Cat", typeof(Cat))
        this.Columns.Add("CatType")

        Cat cat1 = new Cat("name1", "type1")
        Cat cat2 = new Cat("name2", "type2")
        this.Rows.add(new object[] {"value","value",cat1,cat1.type} )
        this.Rows.add(new object[] {"value","value",cat2,cat2.type} )

        // I want to show table like: 
        // |value|value|name1|type1|
        // |value|value|name2|type2|

        // while type should be a reference not a static string, so
        cat1.type = "type3"; //should be able to change table like:

        // |value|value|name1|type3|
        // |value|value|name2|type2|    
    }
} 

class Cat
{
    string name;
    string type;
    public Cat(...){..}

    public override string toString()
        return name;
}
```

Or maybe sth like having table in table?:

```
class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable
    {
        this.Columns.Add("col1");
        this.Columns.Add("col2")        
        this.Columns.Add("Cat", typeof(Cat))

        Cat cat1 = new Cat("name1", "type1")
        Cat cat2 = new Cat("name2", "type2")
        this.Rows.add(new object[] {"value","value",cat1} )
        this.Rows.add(new object[] {"value","value",cat2} )

        // And show table like: 
        // |value|value||name1|type1||
        // |value|value||name2|type2||
    }
} 

 class Cat : DataTable {
      public Cat(string name, string type){
        this.Columns.Add("name");
        this.Columns.Add("type");
        this.Rows.Add(name,type);
      } 
 }
```

But with able to display Cat columns in:

```
 datagridview1.DataSource = new MyDataTable();
```

////

@rene Answer

When I set 'type' as LiveString while having:

```
datagridview.datasource = new List<Cat>(...)
```

And try to edit from datagridview GUI cell associated to this object, I get:

```
System.FormatException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'syb_con.LiveString'. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'syb_con.LiveString'.

  at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)

   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)

   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ChangeType(Object value, Type type, IFormatProvider formatInfo)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ChangeType(Object value, Type type, IFormatProvider formatInfo)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ParseObjectInternal(Object value, Type targetType, Type sourceType, TypeConverter targetConverter, TypeConverter sourceConverter, IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue)

   at System.Windows.Forms.Formatter.ParseObject(Object value, Type targetType, Type sourceType, TypeConverter targetConverter, TypeConverter sourceConverter, IFormatProvider formatInfo, Object formattedNullValue, Object dataSourceNullValue)

   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.ParseFormattedValueInternal(Type valueType, Object formattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter)

   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.ParseFormattedValue(Object formattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter)

   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PushFormattedValue(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCurrentCell, Object formattedValue, Exception& exception)
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Please don't edit my answer. If you have a new question feel free to [ask] one, or if you have extra information in the context of your current question click [edit].

Answer (score 0):

The DataTable is really aimed at storing the state at the moment you add the row to it. Your use case seem to be beyond its design capabilities.

The trick you used for adding the object can also be used for the type if we are allowed to replace the immutable type string  for your `Type` property with a type that does allow to change its value. We use the fact that for DataColumns of the type Object the Row will call `ToString` on that object.

I'll introduce a new type called `LiveString`

```
class LiveString 
{
    string value;

    internal string Value {
        get{return value;}
        set{this.value= value;}
    }

    public LiveString(string value) {
       this.value = value;
    }

    // use an implicit operator
    public static implicit operator LiveString(string value)
    {
        return new LiveString(value);
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

It's aim to wrap a string and have methods to create new objects from strings but also fetch and change its internal state. I used a [conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/85w54y0a.aspx) so the current users of the `Cat` class don't have to change much of their code.

You'll have to adapt your code as follows:

```
class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable()
    {
        this.Columns.Add("col1");
        this.Columns.Add("col2");        
        this.Columns.Add("Cat", typeof(Cat));
        // notice the typeof here
        this.Columns.Add("CatType", typeof(LiveString));

        Cat cat1 = new Cat("name1", "type1");
        Cat cat2 = new Cat("name2", "type2");
        this.Rows.Add(new object[] {"value","value",cat1,cat1.type} );
        this.Rows.Add(new object[] {"value","value",cat2,cat2.type} );

        cat1.type = "type3"; 
    }
}
```

And your Cat class. Notice how on the setter of type I'm not replacing the current object on `_type` but only the `Value` of it. That guarantees that the instance that is held by the Row gets updated, instead of being replaced with a new instance that isn't stored or updated in the Row.

```
class Cat
{
    string name;
    LiveString _type;
    public LiveString type {
        get 
        { 
            return _type;
        }
        set 
        {
            _type.Value = value.Value;
        }
    }

    public Cat(string name, string type){this.name= name; this._type = type;}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This example tries to stay as close a possible to the use of the DataTable. You could instead build your own Collection that you feed with meta data about the types it holds and how you want to represent them. I think [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) can be useful in that implementation space. Other options might be the use of [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).

Comment: That will work. You seem to be looking for a typed collection that you can use for databinding. There are plenty possibities in that case. DataTable is a .net 1.0 concept before generics, linq, dyanamic and anonymous types existed.